# show that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left[\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1-x^2}\right]dx=\pi$

Tags: integration

Most integrals involved $\ln(x)$ seem to produced results of $\pi^2$, $\sqrt\pi$, $\pi\ln(2)$ etc, but rarely $\pi$ on its own.

Here is one

(1)
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left[\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1-x^2}\right]dx=\pi$$

I can't remembered where I got the idea to prompted me to search for this result. Anyway, if anyone got integrals involving $\ln(x)$ that give simple $\pi$ answer I would like to see it.

Can anyone prove (1)?

---

An attempt using integration by parts

$$=\int_{0}^{1}2x^{-2}\ln(1+x^2)dx-\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2}\ln(1-x^2)dx$$

$$=\left.(-x^{-1})\ln(1+x^2)\right|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx+\left.(-x^{-1})\ln(1-x^2)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}
\frac{2}{1-x^2}dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1-x^2}dx$$

I am stuck on the last integral, it doesn't make sense, I am keep getting a zero result. Please lend a hand here.

Comment: You are missing a couple of factors of two in the expansion of the first integral as well; the correct answer should be $-\ln 4 + \pi$.

Comment: The first part $\int2x^{-2}\ln(1+x^2)\ dx$ is fine and integrates to $\pi-2\ln2$. But the second part $-\int x^2\ln(1-x^2)\ dx$ needs a good deal of care. It does indeed integrate to $2\ln2$. But it is easy to split it into two infinite integrals, as you have done. Note that your $-x^{-1}\ln(1-x^2)|_0^1$ evaluates to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}\right)\implies$$

$$\int_0^1\frac2{1-x^2}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\;\left.\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|_0^{1-\epsilon} \;...\;\text{doesn't exist finitely}$$

and thus this improper integral doesn't converge.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite correct to do an *indefinite* integration by parts

$$\int{\log(1-x^2)\over x^2}dx=-{\log(1-x^2)\over x}-\int{2\over1-x^2}dx$$

but it is *incorrect* to write

$$\int_0^1{\log(1-x^2)\over x^2}dx=-{\log(1-x^2)\over x}\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1{2\over1-x^2}dx$$

This is because you're dealing with an *improper* integral, so that the right hand side, as written, has the meaningless indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.  What you need to do instead is finish off the indefinite integration, obtaining

$$\int{\log(1-x^2)\over x^2}dx=-{\log(1-x^2)\over x}+\log(1-x)-\log(1+x)+C$$

and then write the improper definite integral as

$$\int_0^1{\log(1-x^2)\over x^2}dx=\lim_{x\to1}\left(-{\log(1-x^2)\over x}+\log(1-x)-\log(1+x)\right)-\lim_{x\to0}\left(-{\log(1-x^2)\over x}+\log(1-x)-\log(1+x)\right)$$

This leaves you with the chore of computing a pair of limits, but that's what you should expect when doing an improper integral.  (Sometimes the limits are trivial to compute, but in this case they aren't.)